# Problem creating Spring framework project in IntelliJ

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, intellij-idea

I am trying to create a Spring project using Spring initializer in IntelliJ ultimate edition according to the [official guide](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/spring-boot.html#custom-configuration-files) of Jetbrains.

All steps go fine including installing the dependencies of the project.

But whenever I try to run the app; the error below shows up stating that "package org.springframework.boot does not exist" which is already installed in my dependencies.

[image: package org.springframework.boot does not exist]

I've gone through every related post to this problem but no luck. I would appreciate if anyone can guide me through this to figure out what it is that's going wrong about this.

This is also my pom.xml content provided below:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>15</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Please report at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA. Attach `build.log` file with debug info enabled. See https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085 for the details how to enable it. Also attach the complete project directory zipped.

Comment: Thanks for submitting the issue, not all the requested info was provided, please follow-up here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-252941.

Answer (score 0):

In the top right side you have got a refresh button to reinitialize the Pom.xml file again. Once maven repositories are all set it will allow you to start the project